# Circe encoder/decoder for subclasses types

Tags: scala, circe

Given the following ADT

```
sealed abstract class GroupRepository(val `type`: String) {
  def name: String
  def repositories: Seq[String]
  def blobstore: String
}
case class DockerGroup(name: String, repositories: Seq[String], blobstore: String = "default") extends GroupRepository("docker")
case class BowerGroup(name: String, repositories: Seq[String], blobstore: String = "default") extends GroupRepository("bower")
case class MavenGroup(name: String, repositories: Seq[String], blobstore: String = "default") extends GroupRepository("maven")
```

Where the value `type` is used to decode which instance to instantiate.

**How can I automatically (or semi-automatically) derive encoders and decoders such I get the following behavior:**

```
> println(MavenGroup("test", Seq("a", "b")).asJson.spaces2)
{
  "type" : "maven",
  "name" : "test",
  "repositories" : [
     "a",
     "b"
  ],
  "blobstore" : "default"
}
> println((MavenGroup("test", Seq("a", "b")): GroupRepository).asJson.spaces2)
{
  "type" : "maven",
  "name" : "test",
  "repositories" : [
     "a",
     "b"
  ],
  "blobstore" : "default"
}
```

The traditional approach of doing

```
object GroupRepository {
  implicit val encoder = semiauto.deriveEncoder[GroupRepository]
  implicit val decoder = semiauto.deriveDecoder[GroupRepository]
}
```

Fails on two fronts:

- It does not serialize the value `type`.
- Does not allow `MavenGroup("test", Seq("a", "b")).asJson`. It only allows the second alternative where `MavenGroup` is first casted to `GroupRepository`.

The best solution I could come up with is:

```
object GroupRepository {
  implicit def encoder[T <: GroupRepository]: Encoder[T] = Encoder.instance(a => Json.obj(
    "type" -> Json.fromString(a.`type`),
    "name" -> Json.fromString(a.name),
    "repositories" -> Json.fromValues(a.repositories.map(Json.fromString)),
    "blobstore" -> Json.fromString(a.blobstore)
  ))
  implicit def decoder[T <: GroupRepository]: Decoder[T] = Decoder.instance(c =>
    c.downField("type").as[String].flatMap {
      case "docker" => c.as[DockerGroup](semiauto.deriveDecoder[DockerGroup])
      case "bower" => c.as[BowerGroup](semiauto.deriveDecoder[BowerGroup])
      case "maven" => c.as[MavenGroup](semiauto.deriveDecoder[MavenGroup])
    }.right.map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
  )
}
```

However it was several shortcomings:

- The encoder was to be specified manually.
- The decoder for each subtype is not being cached since it is necessary to pass the encoder explicitly.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am the creator of the linked project. 

It looks like you have the same problem I tried solving in a generic way in this project: https://github.com/drivetribe/circe-field-hints

Have a look at it, if you think that that's the solution I'll create a proper answer for it.

Comment: Its not exactly what I want since my class hierarchy already defines the values for the `type`, whereas you explicitly pass the `type` when you invoke the HintedEncoder.derive. However it helps me a lot and I can inspect your code to come up with a solution to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can define encoder/decoder (codec) for each case class as `val` it will not be created each time:

```scala
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveCodec
import io.circe.Codec

private implicit val dockerCodec: Codec.AsObject[DockerGroup] = deriveCodec[DockerGroup]
private implicit val bowerCodec: Codec.AsObject[BowerGroup] = deriveCodec[BowerGroup]
private implicit val mvnCodec: Codec.AsObject[MavenGroup] = deriveCodec[MavenGroup]
```

### Approach 1: something like *fabric* of codecs

I think there is no way to do such a universal codec without `isInstanceOf` but I can mistake.

So, I would define codec for some `T` which uses concrete codec depends on `type` field:

```scala
import io.circe.Decoder.Result
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveCodec
import io.circe.{Codec, HCursor, Json}
import io.circe.syntax._


object Codecs {
  private implicit val dockerCodec: Codec.AsObject[DockerGroup] = deriveCodec[DockerGroup]
  private implicit val bowerCodec: Codec.AsObject[BowerGroup] = deriveCodec[BowerGroup]
  private implicit val mvnCodec: Codec.AsObject[MavenGroup] = deriveCodec[MavenGroup]
  
  implicit def codec[T <: GroupRepository]: Codec[T] = new Codec[T] {
    override def apply(a: T): Json =
      (a match {
        case d: DockerGroup => d.asInstanceOf[DockerGroup].asJsonObject
        case b: BowerGroup => b.asInstanceOf[BowerGroup].asJsonObject
        case m: MavenGroup => m.asInstanceOf[MavenGroup].asJsonObject
      }).+:("type", a.`type`.asJson).asJson

    override def apply(c: HCursor): Result[T] = c.downField("type").as[String].flatMap {
      case "docker" => c.as[DockerGroup]
      case "bower" => c.as[BowerGroup]
      case "maven" => c.as[MavenGroup]
    }.map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
  }
}

object Test extends App {

  import Codecs._
  println(DockerGroup("doc", Seq("a", "b")).asJson)
  println(DockerGroup("doc", Seq("a", "b")).asJson.as[DockerGroup])

  println(BowerGroup("bow", Seq("a", "b")).asJson)
  println(BowerGroup("bow", Seq("a", "b")).asJson.as[BowerGroup])

  println(MavenGroup("mvn", Seq("a", "b")).asJson)
  println(MavenGroup("mvn", Seq("a", "b")).asJson.as[MavenGroup])
}
```

output:

```
{
  "type" : "docker",
  "name" : "doc",
  "repositories" : [
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  "blobstore" : "default"
}
Right(DockerGroup(doc,List(a, b),default))
{
  "type" : "bower",
  "name" : "bow",
  "repositories" : [
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  "blobstore" : "default"
}
Right(BowerGroup(bow,List(a, b),default))
{
  "type" : "maven",
  "name" : "mvn",
  "repositories" : [
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  "blobstore" : "default"
}
Right(MavenGroup(mvn,List(a, b),default))
```

### Approach 2: get rid of `type` field and use configurable derivation

We can define *discriminator* field `type` in our `Configuration` for parsing JSON and get rid of this field in parent `abstract class GroupRepository` (it can be a trait now).
Here I use some ad-hoc discriminator to get similar result of `type` field in result json, but I think in this approach it could be more elegant:

```scala
constructorName => constructorName.toLowerCase.dropRight("Group".length)
```

Remember, for using `ConfiguredJsonCodec` annotation you should define `implicit val config: Configuration` in the companion object. Also, you should add `-Ymacro-annotations` flag to the scala compiler for macroses:

```scala
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Ymacro-annotations")
```

Full code:

```scala
import io.circe.Decoder.Result
import io.circe.generic.extras.{Configuration, ConfiguredJsonCodec}
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.{Codec, HCursor, Json}
import ru.hardmet.GroupRepository._

@ConfiguredJsonCodec
sealed trait GroupRepository {
  def name: String

  def repositories: Seq[String]

  def blobstore: String
}

case class DockerGroup(name: String, repositories: Seq[String], blobstore: String = "default")
  extends GroupRepository

case class BowerGroup(name: String, repositories: Seq[String], blobstore: String = "default")
  extends GroupRepository

case class MavenGroup(name: String, repositories: Seq[String], blobstore: String = "default")
  extends GroupRepository

object GroupRepository {
  implicit val config: Configuration =
    Configuration.default
      .withDiscriminator("type").copy(
      transformConstructorNames = _.toLowerCase.dropRight("Group".length)
    )
}

object GroupRepositoryCodec {
  implicit def codec[T <: GroupRepository]: Codec[T] = new Codec[T] {
    override def apply(a: T): Json = a.asInstanceOf[GroupRepository].asJson

    override def apply(c: HCursor): Result[T] = c.as[GroupRepository].map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
  }
}

object JsonExperiments extends App {

  import GroupRepositoryCodec._

  println(DockerGroup("doc", Seq("a", "b")).asJson)
  println(DockerGroup("doc", Seq("a", "b")).asJson.as[DockerGroup])

  println(BowerGroup("bow", Seq("a", "b")).asJson)
  println(BowerGroup("bow", Seq("a", "b")).asJson.as[BowerGroup])

  println(MavenGroup("mvn", Seq("a", "b")).asJson)
  println(MavenGroup("mvn", Seq("a", "b")).asJson.as[MavenGroup])
}
```

the output will be the same with a difference - `type` field in JSON goes to the end of object:

```json
{
  "name" : "doc",
  "repositories" : [
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  "blobstore" : "default",
  "type" : "docker"
}
```